# Error "does not exist" using web3.eth.personal.sign

Tags: web3js, signature

In [Error using web3.eth.personal.sign](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/43472/error-using-web3-eth-personal-sign) , the problem with the number of arguments was resolved. But now that I can try the actual call, I'm getting a "does not exist" error.

```
console.log("Calling personal.sign");
this.web3.eth.personal.sign(this.bottleDataToSign, this.addressProdFrom, this.passwordProd)
  .then((sig)=>{
    console.log("sig="+sig);
```

Console:

```
Calling personal.sign
ERROR
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Returned error: The method personal_sign does not exist/is not available ErrorResponse onreadystatechange wrapFn onInvokeTask runTask invokeTask invokeTask globalZoneAwareCallback
```

In node_modules/web3-eth-personal/src/index.js, it looks like "sign" actually calls "personal_sign":

```
new Method({
        name: 'sign',
        call: 'personal_sign',
        params: 3,
        inputFormatter: [formatters.inputSignFormatter, formatters.inputAddressFormatter, null]
    }),
```

Poking around in other node_modules/web3 directories/files, I didn't see any declaration for it:

```
$ grep -r "personal_sign" web3*
web3-core-helpers/src/formatters.js: * Hex encodes the data passed to eth_sign and personal_sign
web3-eth-personal/src/index.js:            call: 'personal_signTransaction',
web3-eth-personal/src/index.js:            call: 'personal_sign',
```

So does this imply the code is just missing? Am I calling it correctly? I'm still using npm web3 package: 1.0.0-beta.33, and used it from an `import  Web3  from "web3";`
Anything else to try? Thanks.

Comment: Has your web3 provider enabled `personal` RPC?

Comment: I don't know. I do have a `web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');     // port# from geth's rpcport` line for the actual web3 variable, but I thought that was only needed for talking to a geth node, which I didn't think personal.sign had to do. If needed, how would I do that? Thanks.

Comment: @gkd720 What command line do you use to launch geth?

Comment: I invoke geth with:
`$ geth --identity "TestNode1" --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "~/ethereum/TestChain1" --port "30303" --nodiscover --ipcdisable --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 2429 --keystore ~/Library/Ethereum/keystore console`
But why does this even matter? I'm just calling a web3 package method, not yet trying to issue a transaction through geth; that was my next step in the flow. Thanks.

Comment: @Ayusha care to elaborate how??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further extensive searching, I now see what @Ayushya and @Ismael were getting at. After adding "personal" to the list of items for option --rcapi, I can successfully call the eth.personal.sign method. Looks like the typings.d.ts still needs manual tweaking, but I guess that's why they call it "beta". Thanks to both of them.

updated: the --rcapi is now deprecated, using --http.api instead

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just for in case you not create the rpc provider by your own but using external provider(like: Infura, Alchemy, Pokt, ...) as they will not support --rpcapi `personal` (Actually, all methods with private key are not supported).

So instead of `web3.eth.personal.sign` you can sign it locally using:

```
web3.eth.accounts.sign(message, privateKey)
```

And get the `signature` from it.